# $push in MongoDb not working?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

my schema looks like this:

```
    var exampleSchema = newSchema({
    profile:{
    experience :[{
              exp : String
    }]
   }
  });
```

this is the codes to update experience in profile collection:

```
exampleSchema.statics.experience = function (id,experience, callback){
var update = {
        $push: {
          'profile.experience': experience
        }
      }
      this.findByIdAndUpdate(id,update,function(err) {
        if (err) {
          callback(err);
        } else {
          callback(null);
        }
      })
```

I was getting error like `The field 'profile.experience' must be an array but is of type String in document {_id: ObjectId('5653f1d852cf7b4c0bfeb54a')}[object Object]`

console.log(experience) is equal to

```
{ exp: 'jlkjlkjlk' }
```

my collection should look like this:

```
experience:[
   {
    exp : "YYYY"
    },
   {
    exp:"xxxx"}
 ]
```

Comment: You are trying to update the field 'profile.experience.**exp**' which is not an array. You must apply $push to 'profile.experience'.

Comment: i'm sorry i'm getting the same error

Comment: Your schema is not well defined. Experience is defined as `experience :[{
              exp : String
    ]}` and should be `experience :[{
              exp : String
    **}]** `

Comment: thankyou,but in my woking example it is properly defined......

Comment: Can you make sure that all records inserted in ' profile.experience ' are arrays? It seems that you have a string in document {_id: ObjectId('5653f1d852cf7b4c0bfeb54a')}

Comment: $set is working properly to add experience.......but i need that to be array.because $set modifies old value

Comment: for chridam:::Error: Unable to invalidate a subdocument that has not been added to an array.

Comment: now its showing like MongoError: exception: The field 'profile.experience' must be an array but is of type Object in document {_id: ObjectId('5653f1d852cf7b4c0bfeb54a')}

Answer (score 2):

Imagine that you have this collection:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("565425e862760dfe14339ba8"),
    "profile" : {
        "experience" : [ 
            {
                "exp" : "Experto"
            }
        ]
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("565425f562760dfe14339ba9"),
    "profile" : {
        "experience" : {
            "exp" : "Experto"
        }
    }
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5654260662760dfe14339baa"),
    "profile" : {
        "experience" : "Experto"
    }
}
```

If you try (update doc /* 2 */):

```
db.profile.update(
   { _id: ObjectId("565425f562760dfe14339ba9") },
   { $push: { "profile.experience" : { exp : "Intermediate" } } }
)
```

You get this error:

> The field 'profile.experience' must be an array but is of type Object
>   in document {_id: ObjectId('565425f562760dfe14339ba9')}

And if you try (update doc /* 3 */):

```
db.profile.update(
   { _id: ObjectId("5654260662760dfe14339baa") },
   { $push: { "profile.experience" : { exp : "Intermediate" } } }
)
```

You will get:

> The field 'profile.experience' must be an array but is of type String
>   in document {_id: ObjectId('5654260662760dfe14339baa')}

Comment: solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

i changed Schema like this

```
 experience          : [{type:String,exp:String}],
```

my update object looks like this

```
 var update = {
    $push: {
      'profile.experience': san.exp
}
};
```

san looks like this :`{ exp: 'YYY' }`

Inside mongoose collectionlooks like this used RoboMongo

```
 "experience" : [ 
        "experienced in XXX", 
        "YYY"
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$push: {
    'profile.experience': experience
}
```

Remove `.exp`.

Comment: i'm getting this error:The field 'profile.experience' must be an array but is of type String in document

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check you declared your field as an array like this(look at field products):

```
   shop = {
        'name': "Apple Store",
        'description': "",
        'direction': "",
        'contact': "",
        'products':[]
    }
```

Now if you want to add something to the field products using $push

```
product = {
        'name': "Iphone 6",
        'description': "Iphone model 6, 64GB",
        'price': 700,
        'count': 3 
    }
 myquery = { "name" : "Apple Store" }
 obj ={"$push":{"products":{"$each": [product]}}}
 db.collection.update_one(myquery,obj)
```

This code is provided for PyMongo framework. To use in MongoDB directly replace update_one by update. [Mongo resource](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `$set` instead of `$push` which might work.

```
$set: {
    'profile.experience': experience
}
```

Comment: yes, it will work only if we already have the experience array, what should happen if there is an update that happened at the same time for experience concurrently then it will have invalid data.... it's better to perform push and pull separately...

Answer (score -1):

are you searching for adding multiple values into single field then use this one.
write this one your model or schema:

```
    arrayremarks:[{remark: String}]
```

then write in your controller:

```
module.exports.addingremarks = (req, res) => {
    let casenum=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body.casenum).replace(/"\s+|\s+"/g,'"'))
    var rem={remark:"Suman macha"}
    Inwart.update( { 'casenum': casenum },{ $push: { arrayremarks:rem} } ,function (err, inwarts) {
        if (err)
         return console.error(err); 
         res.send(inwarts);  
     }
  )
}
```